# laravel 5 - Eloquent relationship two tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm new in Laravel, I have 2 class Model (table Customer and Order):

```
table Customer, with columns:
  - id_cust (PK)
  - name

table Order, with columns:
  - id_order (PK)
  - id_cust (FK to table Customer)
  - product_name
  - qty
```

I try make model for "Customer":

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_cust';
    protected $table = 'customer';
}
```

and model for class 'Order':

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_order';
    protected $table = 'order';
}
```

In SQL:

```
select a.id_cust, a.name, b.product, b.qty
  from customer a, order b
 where a.id_cust = b.id_cust;
```

I want output like this:

```
========================================
|id_cust  |name    |product    |qty    |
|======================================|
|10       |jeff    |Plastic    |10     |
|10       |jeff    |Book       |2      |
|11       |james   |Laptop     |1      |
|11       |james   |TV         |1      |
|12       |davy    |shoe       |1      |
========================================
```

I try in controller, but failed:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\customer;
use App\order;

class ShowDetail extends Controller
{

  public function index(){

    $aa = customer->where('customer.id_cust','=','order.id_cust')->order-get();
    var_dump($aa);
  }
}
```

any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in the order model:

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

customer model:

```
public function order(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

and then in controller:

```
public function index(){
    $aa= Customer::with('orders')->get();
    var_dump($aa);
}
```

Comment: hi Xhulio, thank you for your answer, but it still failed, can you show me which part that explain relation between "... customer.id_cust = order.id_cust..."? thank you.

Comment: okay in your original code try this: `$aa = customer->where('customer.id_cust','order.id_cust')->get();`

Comment: @Firdi the relation is in the `customer()` and `order()` methods in your models. however you should also define them in your database model